# SSRS Interface in MVC

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting

How can i use  in this Example :

```html
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
                reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
                IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("user", "pass", "domain");
                reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
                //reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/"+ URLReport;
                reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("url"); <-- Here
                ViewBag.ReportViewer = reportViewer;
                return View();
```

In the same code,If I use http://servername/reportServer no mistake, but if i use http://servername/reports i have :

*The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version.
La demande a échoué avec l'état HTTP 404 : Not Found.*

Comment: They are two different API's. So if reportServer works, whats the problem?

Comment: Looks like an issue with the datasource or your link to the report from the reportServer.  You likely need to look at connection strings to make sure they are directing to the correct locations.